# Not able to Delete or Activate Approval Process

Tags: approval-process, delete

For some strange reason, I am not able delete or activate Approval process.

Proof : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuOQ9.jpg

If someone can help me understand why that will be great

Comment: Could you please try once in classic mode.

Comment: Try Firefox or Safari; or Classic - see [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002BRMXQA4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I liked the most was to use Visual Studio Code (VSC) to extract the ApprovalProcess metadata.

**For Delete :**

In VSC, Choose "Delete from Project and Source"

**For Activating inactive AP:**

Edit the metadata from Inactive to Active.
Then Deploy via VSC

Answer (score 0):

Try in classic mode.
Also try in classic while in incognito mode in Chrome, to ensure none of your extensions are interfering.